# HQL IF clause not work with IS NOT NULL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have below HQL query.

```
@Query("SELECT IF ( job.doneDate IS NOT NULL ) THEN SUM( jobCost.amount ) FROM JobCost AS jobCost "
        + "LEFT JOIN jobCost.job AS job WHERE job.code = :#{#filter.jobCode} "
        + "AND jobCost.costType = :#{#filter.jobCostType} "
        + "AND jobCost.job.business.id = :#{#filter.searchBusiness} "
        + "AND jobCost.date >= :job.doneDate "
        + "AND jobCost.date <= :#{#filter.endDate} ELSE 0.00 END")
```

I got this error on console.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: THEN near line 1, column 40 [SELECT IF ( job.doneDate IS NOT NULL ) THEN SUM( jobCost.amount ) FROM com.job.JobCost AS jobCost LEFT JOIN jobCost.job AS job WHERE job.code = :__$synthetic$__1 AND jobCost.costType = :__$synthetic$__2 AND jobCost.job.business.id = :__$synthetic$__3 AND jobCost.date >= :job.doneDate AND jobCost.date <= :__$synthetic$__4 ELSE 0.00 END]
```

How should I correct this ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What query syntax is this?

Comment: @fateddy spring Annotation query. I'm trying to get sum of 'jobCost.amount' filed.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN job.doneDate IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(jobCost.amount) ELSE 0.00 END FROM JobCost AS jobCost "
    + "LEFT JOIN jobCost.job AS job WHERE job.code = :#{#filter.jobCode} "
    + "AND jobCost.costType = :#{#filter.jobCostType} "
    + "AND jobCost.job.business.id = :#{#filter.searchBusiness} "
    + "AND jobCost.date >= :job.doneDate "
    + "AND jobCost.date <= :#{#filter.endDate}")
```

Please Note: ELSE is not acceptable in WHERE condition and you can handle this by CASE WHEN  IS NOT NULL THEN .. ELSE ...END.

please refer: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html